# How do I retrieve html table values(text) using Selenium 1 C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, selenium, html-table

I apologize if a question such as this has already been addressed.
I am attempting to retrieve text displayed in an HTML table in a website using Selenium (webdriver).  I am programming using C# in Visual Studios 2010.  The Html looks as below:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <tr id="RFCol">
        <th class="subhead">
            <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="BROCHURE " style="width: 60px; height: 12px;">
            <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="FARE" style="width: 24px; height: 12px;">
        </th>
        <td class="">
            <span id="RFCol1" class="RFCol">
                <del>$5,190</del>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="">
            <span id="RFCol2" class="RFCol">
                <del>$6,660</del>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="">
        <td class="">
        <td class="">
    </tr>
    <tr id="PFCol">
    <tr id="CSDCol">
    <tr id="PFCol">
</tbody>
```

The bold texts are what I'm after. I'm attempting to store the text in a string variable to prepare it to be written to a text file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been unable to achieve this.  A few attempts of mine are below. I tried to use the xpath to retrieve the value but could not.

```
IWebElement table_element11 = selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span/del"));
```

Comment: Hey all. I figured out the issue, or partially anyhow.  I am still unable to utilize the commands such as GetText() or GetTable(), which is weird since i am using Selenium and webdriver pack.  But anyhow.  A very simple solution is just to access the element using the xpath as above. Then simply turn the object to text :            IWebElement table_element11 = selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span/del"));                                 table_element11.text; (this will return the desired result)

Comment: you can write an answer yourself or delete the whole question if you think no one else would need your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
"//del[contains(., '$')]"
```

Using this XPath will give you all of the 'del' elements on the page that contain the $ sign.  From this point, you can use the method you wish to access the data, like you stated in your comment.

Comment: For some reason i was unable to accomplish this using that Xpath, which was part of my problem.   Using the "other" XPath to access the page element, i just transformed it into text.  Thank you all for the help!